# How to extract string from another string between the Nth and N+1th 'breakword' in php?

Tags: php

My example code is given below.

```
$a= "I think there are many people who can help in my difficulty. breakword Thank you in advance. brwakword If i got this solution I will be happy. Breakword I have already searched in google about it I did not get it's solution. Breakword If you have any link of solution please help me. breakword Thank you again!";
```

From the above string I want to get the sentence between 2nd and 3rd 'breakword' word.
It means I want to extract 'If i got this solution I will be happy.'.
If you have any solution please help me. Thank you in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can split your string into smaller parts using `explode()` and get the "Nth" part of the array.

```
$sentences = explode('breakword', $a);
echo $sentences[2];
```

PHP > 5.4 will support this too :

```
echo explode('breakword', $a)[2];
```

Comment: sidenote: actually 5.4 supports dereference on functions

Comment: can you please provide me code to count the no of breakword in that string

Comment: @AnilBhattarai100 This in another question, I won't answer that here. Try searching it on Stack Overflow (it has already been asked for sure) or on Google first, and if you really can't find any solution, ask a whole new question.

Answer (score 1):

a similar approach but intead of using `explode` you can also use `preg_split`

supports `(PHP 4, PHP 5)`

`preg_split('/breakword/', $a);`

Comment: can you have code to count no of 'breakword in that string'

Comment: @AnilBhattarai100 `substr_count()`

Comment: @AnilBhattarai100 `preg_match_all('/breakword/', $a)` will return number of `breakword` but that is entirely a different question :D

Answer (score 1):

for the second answer you can use

```
$dummy=array();
preg_match_all('/breakword/', $a,$dummy)
```